# Injected javascript in google DFP module drupal 7

Tags: 7, javascript

Currently I am setting up the Google DFP module and I have been trying to work out how the JavaScript is working. In the module there is a section for injecting JavaScript which is what Google DFP will give you to place in the head tag on the website. When I place the JavaScript in the form where it tells me to place it, when I load the page up it shows some of the JavaScript at the top in the body (using the DFP module).

So I experimented around with this and took the JavaScript out. I was expecting the adverts to stop displaying, however they kept displaying after taking out the JavaScript and deleting the cache and I am confused as to how it is displaying the correct adverts.

Sadly I can't give a link to the website because I am using eclipse to test things out.

The module I am using is: [Doubleclick for Publishers (DFP)](https://drupal.org/project/dfp)

What I would like to know is how is this working? The JavaScript isn't there so how does it know what adverts to get? The only thing the module knows is the network ID and the advert tags using the `[dfp_tag:slot]` token.

Answer (score 1):

you can take a look at these functions (_dfp_js_global_settings and _dfp_js_slot_definition) that are used to inject inline javascript in the page, I believe that javascript loads the ads remotely and inject them in their spots